# strcat not behaving as desired

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, fgets, strcat

I'm trying to write a program that takes user input twice, then concatenates the result, but I'm running into an issue.

My expected output would be:

```
What would you like your message to be? input
message received: input

What would you like your message to be? words
message received: words

new message: inputwords
```

Instead I'm receiving a garbled response.

Received output:

```
What would you like your message to be? input
message received: input

What would you like your second message to be? words
message received: words

new message: ??s?inputwords
```

First question:

How can I concatenate these two strings correctly?

Additionally:

Since I'm only accepting 5 chars of input for each message, how would I go about clearing out the remaining elements in the buffer between these fgets calls without reading the remainder into the "garbage" array?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {

    char message[6];
    char garbage[9999];
    char message2[6];

    printf("\nWhat would you like your message to be? ");
    fgets(message, 6, stdin);

    printf("message received: %s\n", message);

    fgets(garbage, 9999, stdin); //this is gross

    printf("\nWhat would you like your second message to be? ");
    fgets(message2, 6, stdin);

    printf("message received: %s\n", message2);

    fgets(garbage, 9999, stdin); //still gross

    char newString[25];
    strcat(newString, message);
    strcat(newString, message2);

    printf("new message: %s\n", newString);
    return 0;

}
```

Note: I am aware that I should be catching the return value for fgets, I left that out for brevity.

Comment: `strcat` appends one string to another. But you called it with uninitialized buffer for argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is

```
char newString[25];
strcat(newString, message);
strcat(newString, message2);
```

`strcat()` assumes the first argument has been initialised using a nul-terminated string.   The first call supplies an uninitialised array, so has undefined behaviour.    To fix, simply change the first call to `strcpy()` - which will copy `message` to `newString` without relying on `newString` being initialised.

To flush a line of input (i.e. read until end of file, a read error, or a newline is encountered) a common technique is

```
int c; 
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
```

However, it is not normally considered a good idea to mix character oriented input (like `fgets()`) with character oriented input (like `fgetc()`) since the two handle things like newlines differently.

An alternative using `fgets()` is

```
char buffer[2];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL && buffer[0] != '\n') {}
```

It is necessary to use a buffer  (the integer `c` in the first form, and `buffer` in the second form).   These two options minimise the size of the needed buffer   (to `sizeof int` using `fgetc()` or to `2` using `fgets()`)

Some folks suggest using `fflush(stdin)`.  That is a bad idea - according to the C standard, `fflush()` gives undefined behaviour on input streams.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` requires a null-terminated string, while your buffer is uninitialized. Replace the first call to `strcat` with a call to `strcpy`:

```
char newString[25];
strcpy(newString, message);
strcat(newString, message2);
```

Alternatively, you can use `sprintf`:

```
char newString[25];
sprintf(newString, "%s%s", message, message2);
```